# Ubuntu 18.04 sticking on reboot with "a stop job is running for Advanced ..."

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I can't figure out why my server is sticking on a reboot:

[image]

I left it running for ages (20+ mins!), and it just keeps sticking on that point. The only way around it is to force a restart again.

Any suggestions on what to check? Ideally, I'd move over to a later version (20.04 etc), but its a bit of a job due to the amount of stuff I'm running on this server

Comment: Check redis's own logs to find out why it is not stopping normally.

Comment: @MichaelHampton typically, its been playing ball since I posted this! I'll keep an eye on it and check the logs the next time it happens.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with my Linode.  It is not possible to check redis's ownlogs in this situation for two reasons:

1) It is impossible to log onto the system while it is in this state.  2) To get out of this state one must apparently restore from backup which wipes out the logs that might inform one of how one got into this state.